# C++ no suitable constructor exists to convert from to

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make it so an input of a string gets multiplied by two the subtract 1. I know that my question has been asked here before, but the problem is that I couldn't really comprehend what it was saying was wrong.

```
string coffeeCode(string input) {           //Coffee code= 2n-1 where n=a number in a string

    vector<double> userInputDoubles;
    istringstream converter(input);
    string token;
    double value{};
    while (getline (converter, token, ',')) {
        value = stod(token);
        value = 2 * value - 1;
        userInputDoubles.push_back(value);

    };


    return value;
};
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] which replicates the error. Add a comment on the line where you get the error. And please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question itself. Lastly please take some time to read (or refresh) about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The function returns a double but its return type is string. There is no default constructor to convert double to string.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a double but its return type is string. There is no default constructor to convert double to string. Return a string:

```
std::string coffeeCode(std::string input) {           //Coffee code= 2n-1 where n=a number in a string

    std::vector<double> userInputDoubles;
    std::istringstream converter(input);
    std::string token;
    double value{};
    while (std::getline (converter, token, ',')) {
        value = std::stod(token);
        value = 2 * value - 1;
        userInputDoubles.push_back(value);

    };


    return std::to_string(value);
};
```

or return a double:

```
double coffeeCode(std::string input) {           //Coffee code= 2n-1 where n=a number in a string

    std::vector<double> userInputDoubles;
    std::istringstream converter(input);
    std::string token;
    double value{};
    while (std::getline (converter, token, ',')) {
        value = std::stod(token);
        value = 2 * value - 1;
        userInputDoubles.push_back(value);

    };


    return value;
};
```